# Group by / Summing values with the same column value

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

i was trying to solve a problem which just looks like the code written below, but from lack of knowledge and reading through the sqlalchemy documentation, i do not really find any solution on how to solve my problem, yet.

Objective: 
 Get summed value of sales_in_usd if year in year_column is same

What I got so far is by debugging and reading a bit through stackoverflow and documentations, google by using following query:

```
session.query(fact_corporate_sales, Company, Sales,
                                                    Time, Sector, func.sum(Sales.sales_in_usd).label('summary')).\
                                join(Sales).\
                                join(Time).\
                                join(Company).\
                                join(Segment).\
                                order_by(Time.year.desc()).\
                        filter(Company.company_name.like(filtered)).\
                                group_by(fact_corporate_sales.fact_cps_id, Company.company_name,fact_corporate_sales.cps_id).\
                                all()
```

And well the fact_cps_id is unique in the fact_table and the same table stores, the keys of the dimension tables as well..

I have a fact table which stores 4 foreign keys from 4 dimension tables.

```
fact_cps_id   company_id   sales_id   time_id  sector_id
   1             4            2          1        2                      
   2             4            1          1        3                          
   3             4            3          2        1          
   4             4            2          2        4                 
   5             4            4          3        2            
   6             4            99         1        1
```

dim_company

```
company_id  company_name
    1          Nike
    2          Adidas
    3          Puma
    4          Reebok
```

dim_segment

```
segment_id  segment_nom
    1         basketball
    2         running
    3         soccer
    4         watersports
```

dim_time

```
time_id  quarter year
  1         1     2013
  2         2     2013
  3         1     2014
  4         3     2014
```

dim_sales

```
sales_id    sales_in_euro
   1           2000
   2           3200
   3           1400
   4           1590
   ..          .. 
   99          1931
```

So basically, as you can see in the table and query what I was trying to do was summing up all sales from the as example dim_Time.year <- from the same year.

If we look into the fact_table we can see, that we have time_id = 1 three times, here. So those values could be summed up and displayed as a summary.

I know from standard SQL that it was possible by using group by and aggregate function sum.

My result(time_id is only for help therefore was no output):

```
13132.0 <- time_id = 1
21201.0 <- time_id = 2 
23923.0 <- time_id = 1
31232.0 <- time_id = 99
32021.0 <- time_id = 2
32342.0 <- time_id = 1 
131231.0 <- time_id = 4
```

I printed the actual query into the console and got this [had to remove .all(), because 'list' has no attribute called 'statement']:

```
SELECT fact_corporate_sales.cps_fact_id, fact_corporate_sales.cps_id, 

fact_corporate_sales.company_id, fact_corporate_sales.time_id,  fact_corporate_sales.segment_id, sum(dim_corporate_sales.sales_in_usd) AS summary
FROM fact_corporate_sales INNER JOIN dim_corporate_sales ON dim_corporate_sales.cps_id = fact_corporate_sales.cps_id INNER JOIN dim_time ON dim_time.time_id = fact_corporate_sales.time_id INNER JOIN dim_company ON dim_company.company_id = fact_corporate_sales.company_id INNER JOIN dim_segment ON dim_segment.segment_id = fact_corporate_sales.segment_id
WHERE dim_company.company_name LIKE %s GROUP BY fact_corporate_sales.cps_fact_id ORDER BY dim_time.year DESC
```

And if I want to group by for example dim_time.Year only..I get following response from mysql or console

```
Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db.fact_corporate_sales.fact_cps_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: And what is the question? What is wrong with your query in the 1st code sample?

Comment: What i get as result is .. wait lemme look

Comment: Ok look the result looks like this .. ->
`32342.0`
`32021.0`
`31232.0`
`23923.0`
`21201.0`
`13132.0`
`13132.0`
`1201.0`

Comment: And how should it look like? Can you pls create some sample data, provide expected output, and the output you are getting?

Comment: Look im visualizing it and the same years should be summed up imgur.com/OA5ZfEJ @Shadow

Comment: Can you print the SQL that's actually getting run? You're not actually grouping by year in your original query.

Comment: Listen, i have tried everything even group_by(Time.year) but with no result and the main problem is when i do group_by and do not include the primary key of my fact table (fact_corporate_sales.cps_fact_id) it throws me some heavy errors. But yeah let me check. As soon as i have the original query I will post and tag you here :) Thanks for response.

Comment: @univerio Look by printing the actual statement .. i get an error because "list" has no attribute called "statement" .. so i removed the .all() from the query and now thats what i get as my statement:

Comment: @adriansdq can you export and post above tables as query

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand @KajaMydeen

Comment: I would like to check your query in my local machine. For that i need to create all tables and have to insert all data. it will take time to do it. So you can export tables as query.

Comment: Uhm its working. Do you still need it? Problem was -> SQL_MODE was set on sql_mode = full_group_by.

I had to set it to sql_mode = ' '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was only to execute following sql:

```
engine.execute("SET sql_mode='';")
```

As the response of my failed query was:

```
"this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"
```

I had to disable the sql_mode and so did I and got my result.

Comment: This helped me get to what I think is an even better solution: `engine.execute("SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));")` (this only removes the mode option that was causing the problem, and leaves all the other options alone)